# How to configure the flow so that Terms and Conditions page appears after 2fa in Keycloak

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have enabled **"Terms and Conditions"** for users from Keycloak admin console.

From **Authentication** tab,
[image]
From **Users** tab,
[image]

I have opted for 2fa action. So when user try to login to application, it ask for otp which we can
get it from Google Authenticator/FreeOTP.

[image]

Now the question is while updating password/registering user "**Terms & Condition**" page appears first then **2fa** page instead of that can I get first 2fa page then accepting "Terms & Conditions" page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reorder priorities here:
[Change flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9BxS.png)

Or create new custom login flow Authentication/flows and there you can set your custom flow.

Comment: Yes, by changing the priority of flow (Authentication-> Required Actions ) it reflects . Thank you